# Manage manually compiled ViM (Debian)

Tags: apt, package-management, vim, compiling

I installed ViM by compiling the source code from GitHub and then I used `checkinstall` to install it on my system.

Now I'd like to install another program with the apt package manager (which is `vifm`), but when I try to install it it tells me that it will install `vim-common` and `vim-addon-manager`. As far as I understand by reading the packages web pages ([vim-common](https://packages.debian.org/stable/vim-common) and [vim-addon-manager](https://packages.debian.org/stable/vim-addon-manager)) I suspect I've already everything installed on my system to install vifm (even though I cannot be 100% sure). How can I install vifm without installing those two packages? Even better, if it turns out I'm right in suspecting that I already have everything those two packages provide installed on my system, how can I make apt aware of it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `apt` command uses `dpkg` as its package database.

If the application was not installed by either of these utilities as a `.deb` package, there is no way they would know about it.

You would want to create a proper `.deb` package for the new version, you should be able to reference the [sources of the current packages](https://packages.debian.org/source/buster/vim) to get an idea of how to do it.

Since the `vifm` package depends on the official `vim-common`, it may also depend on the specific version that is provided by the distribution.  In which case, you would need to also build `vifm` from source.

Comment: So, when I run checkinstall to build the .deb package, I should reference all the packages in the page you linked me in the section "provides", is it correct?

Comment: I am not familiar with `checkinstall`, but that does sound like it would convince your package database that the functionality is installed.  I normally just take the source `.deb` and modify what needs to be changed (in your case, you want to update the version so you would include an updated source archive).